# Can I do an ID foreach instance of class?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm a newbie in c#. I am just trying to do an ID for each instance in class Person.

```
class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            countPersons++;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public string name { private get; set; }
        public int age { private get; set;}
        private static int countPersons { get; set; }
        
        public void GetNameAndAge()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}");
        }
        public void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}\nId: {countPersons}");
        }

    }
```

I want every class instance to have an id that starts from one (one, two, three, etc.)

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var player1 = new Person("David", 31);
            var player2 = new Person("Brad", 23);
            var player3 = new Person("Michael", 26);

            player1.GetNameAndAge();
            player1.GetInfo();
            player2.GetInfo();
            player3.GetInfo();
        }
    }
```

But at the end of the program, the ID for everyone is 3...
(The variable countPersons is my ID)

Comment: When you construct a new `Person` object you should assign the current value of `countPersons` after (or before) the increment, to a non-static member, e.g. `id`.

Comment: There's no `ID` property in `Person`. You increment the static field `countPersons` but never use it. Why do you want an `ID` anyway?

Comment: But the default of the int is 0 so its don't matter in this case...

Comment: Unrelated: Just a tip - it's usually not a good idea to save "age". You would rather save "DateOfBirth" and compute age when you need it.

Comment: Making the _getters_ of public properties private seems also _very odd_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hold that in variable or property.

```
class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            id = countPersons++;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        int id;
        public string name { private get; set; }
        public int age { private get; set;}
        private static int countPersons { get; set; }
        
        public void GetNameAndAge()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}");
        }
        public void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}\nId: {id}");
        }

    }
```

Note:

- Static will increase with each instance creation.
- id will hold that vlaue.

Comment: Mind that this is not thread safe. You _could_ end up with two instances having the same id. (Yes, I know: this is really nitpickky, but possible)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the `id` as property like

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(int id, string name, int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int id { private get; set; }
    public string name { private get; set; }
    public int age { private get; set; }
    private static int countPersons { get; set; }

    public void GetNameAndAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}");
    }
    public void GetInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Player name: {name ?? "unknown"} | Player age: {age}\nId: {countPersons}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes just realized, it's from the question. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using a static countPersons and assigning to that.

Instead you could use a for loop in the main function and pass that index in to the Person constructor. This way you would have IDs like 0,1,2,…